# Python Lock Vs RLock

Tags: python, multithreading, locking

I know RLock can be acquiree for many times before it releases. And my question is in the following case, can i use multiple Locks instead of using RLock. I ran it and it works fine as my expectation.

```
import threading

##declare two locks, is that good way to do like this or using RLock
outer_lock = threading.Lock()
lock = threading.Lock()
t = []

def get_first_part():
    lock.acquire()
    global t
    try:
        t.append('first')
    finally:
        lock.release()
    return t

def get_second_part():
    lock.acquire()
    global t
    try:
        t.append('second')
    finally:
        lock.release()
    return t


def get_both_part():
    outer_lock.acquire()
    try:
        first = get_first_part()
        second = get_second_part()
    finally:
        outer_lock.release()
    return first, second

t1 = threading.Thread(target=get_both_part)
t2 = threading.Thread(target=get_both_part)

t1.start()
t2.start()
t1.join()
t2.join()
```

Comment: The question is, why would you _want_ to use multiple locks instead of one? It makes it a lot easier to screw up and deadlock your program, it makes your code more complex, it doesn't scale nicely to dynamically-deep recursive locking, and I wouldn't expect it to reduce contention or work any faster (although I wouldn't rule that out without testing).

Comment: In this case, I think it is equivalent. When you also use "three", it does not need to produce equivalent, expected behavior.

Comment: I would recommend using context manager  'with' -http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/context_managers.html instead of try: finally: